# Doubly Linked List, Removing First Occurrence

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I am having trouble figuring out how to remove a first occurrence node.

So far here is my code for removing the first occurrence node.

```
public boolean remove(E doomedElt)
{
    if (head == null)
        return false;

    else if (doomedElt.equals(head.data))
    {
        removeFirst();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        DLLNode<E> cursor = head;
        while(cursor.next != null && !cursor.next.data.equals(doomedElt))
            cursor = cursor.next;

        if (cursor.next.next == null && cursor.next.data.equals(doomedElt))
        {
            removeLast();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor.next = cursor.next.next;
            cursor.next.next.prev = cursor.prev;  //<---Stuck here.
            cursor.prev = cursor.prev.prev;       //<---And here.

            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code for removing last:

```
public E removeLast()
{
    if (tail == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot removeFirst from empty list");
    else if (head == tail)
    {
        E firstOne = head.data;      
        head = tail = null;
        return firstOne;
    }
    else
    {
        E lastOne = tail.data;     
        tail = tail.prev;
        tail.next = null;
        return lastOne;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for removing first:

```
public E removeFirst()
{
    if (head == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot removeFirst from empty list");
    else if (head == tail)
    {
        E firstOne = head.data;     
        head = tail = null;
        return firstOne;
    }
    else
    {
        E firstOne = head.data;     
        head = head.next;
        head.prev = null;
        return firstOne;
    }
}
```

When I run my driver, which will add `(4, 5, 6 ,5, 7, 6)`. From there I tell it to remove the first `6`. What I should be getting is a `(4, 5, 5, 7 ,6)` following the `.next` link (which I do get), and following the `.prev` link I should be getting `(6, 7, 5, 5, 4)`. Instead, I am getting `(6, 7, 4)`.

However, when I remove the `cursor.next.next.prev = cursor.prev;` and `cursor.prev = cursor.prev.prev;` The `.prev` link goes back to the original but just backwards. Which means that my logic for reconnecting the `.prev` link in incorrect.

Can someone please help to with the logic for reconnect the .`prev` link, by bypassing the node.

Comment: get some pen and paper, and run through the code you wrote yourself, as if you were the computer, with a short list as input. What does it build, and what do you see happening to your prev/next pointers when you then manually run through the "first occurence removal" scenario? You don't need us to help you figure this one out, you just need to take a bit of time to run through your code instead of staring at it in a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
cursor.next = cursor.next.next;
cursor.next.next.prev = cursor.prev;  //<---Stuck here.
cursor.prev = cursor.prev.prev;       //<---And here.
```

Should be changed to this:

```
cursor.next = cursor.next.next;
cursor.next.prev = cursor;
```

Because cursor is the position before the element removed. I.e. if you have A B and C and you are removing B, the next of A should become C and the previous of C should become A.

Note this code is untested but it should work - let me know if not and I will help more.

Comment: Oh... I see why my code was wrong. When I have the code `cursor.next = cursor.next.next;` According to the `.next` link there is no B it is just (A, C). Then from there I just tell it to the cursor to follow the `.next` then `.prev` back to itself. This whole time I keep on thinking that B was in there till all of the links have bypassed B. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, happy to help